# Node Js installation error, getting an error while starting npm

Tags: node.js

I installed node js v13.14.0 on my machine but when I am trying to hit node -version it gives me an error saying node: bad option: -version whereas it works for npm -v and node -v. Also, complete command npm -version works.

And I am not able to start npm with npm start command. Can somebody plz help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `node --version`.

`npm start` is actually performing task(s) defined in a `package.json` within your project. Usually you will get an error if you run `npm start` in a directory without a `package.json`. In case other errors occur, npm usually gives a detailed output of what went wrong.

Comment: Now I am getting something like this on starting npm @chilyiskult . node --version is working perfectly.

Comment: D:\React>npm start
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\React\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pg5050107\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-08T14_16_01_974Z-debug.log

Comment: This is exactly what I referred to in my answer. There is no package.json in your D:\React folder.